# Change Owner button missing from certain profiles

Tags: leads, record-owner, lead-owner

The Change Owner button on lead list views are missing from some users in the company.

I guess this is due to their profiles that they cannot see it, or is there another reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

In Salesforce, Record owner change `[change]` link is only available when the user having some permission as mentioned in this [blog](https://www.simplysfdc.com/2015/12/salesforce-change-record-owner.html).

And this is the basic permission need to get Owner change `[Change]` link in records:

- You are the record owner and you have Edit permission on the object **[OR]**
- Record owned by a user under you in the role hierarchy (Grant Access Using Hierarchies must be enabled for that object) and you have Edit permission on the object.

*Note: This answers are not included the records of the object which is available as Child for any object in master details relationship.*

Please let me know if it helps.